# An application would like access to an out-of-date version of Java: warning while invoking JNLP file

Tags: java, jar, java-web-start, jnlp

I am seeing a warning message whenever i am trying to invoke jnlp file from my website.

Message

[image]

I have security attribute inside JNLP file is set to all permissions. I have signed this jar as well.

JNLP file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost:8080/" href="Timesheet.jnlp">

     <information>
          <title> Foo</title>
          <vendor>bla</vendor>
          <homepage href="http://localhost:8080/" />
          <description>Timesheet JNLP Application</description>
     </information>

     <security>
          <all-permissions/>
     </security>

     <resources>
          <j2se version="1.6*" />
          <jar href="Timesheet.jar" />
     </resources>

     <application-desc main-class="com.data.JNLPApp" />
</jnlp>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```xml
<j2se version="1.6*" />
```

This is asking for any version of 1.6, which is two major releases out of date. Oracle has come to a point where they don't wish to allow older versions of Java to be used for Java apps., because they might have security bugs.

To get around that, change that to:

```xml
<j2se version="1.6+" />
```

That specifies any of 1.6, 1.7, 1.8 ..or whatever later version of Java might be installed on the user machine.

Comment: Thanks Andrew Thompson sir, I did something similar to get over this problem.